# How can i compare the numeric values of the last two fields in a file?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that contains the following information

```
   organic_apple;2;organic_apple_212_212
   organic_tomato;3;organic_tomato_24_29
    fruit_juice;5;fruit_juice_15_15
```

So i want a file that contains the output

```
organic_apple;2;organic_apple_212
organic_tomato;3;organic_tomato_24_29
fruit_juice;5;fruit_juice_15
```

compare the last two fields, if they are the same display it once , if not , display them both 
I'm writing in unix bash using solaris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the number of underscores, compare the last two:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}$NF==$(NF-1){--NF;$1=$1}1' test.in
```

Comment: But what does the --NF stand for ? can you explain the whole syntax just to make sure that i get it ? I know NF is the number of lines and FS is the field separator

Comment: `NF` is the number of fields on a line. `NF--` essentially tells awk to drop the last column. (`NR` is the number of rows seen so far).

Comment: Some versions of awk don't update the final output if you just change `NF`, they have to be tricked into thinking one of the fields in the row changed. `$1=$1` does that. The `1` on the end tells awk to print every row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk -vOFS=_ -F_ '{if ($2 == $3) print $1, $2; else print $1, $2, $3}' file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, and simple to understand/remember ;)

Answer (score 0):

This script removes the last field, if it is equal to the one before last:

```
awk -F "_" '$NF==$(NF-1){$NF=""}1' file
```